# SQL Server Replication - Transactional

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, database-replication, sql-server-2019

I am trying to do  SQL Server transactional replication. Created publisher, distributor & subscriber.

Publisher & distributes in SQL server A and subscriber on SQL server B.

From server A I can connect to Server B working with SQL user.

But when doing replication getting error

Error messages:

> The process could not connect to Subscriber '10.X.X.XX'. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL20084)

> Get help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL20084

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 18452)

> Get help: http://help/18452

How to solve this issue.

Tried to enable port 1433 on Firewall.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't configure replication to use sql login when connecting